# Call function from parent module in imported module

Tags: python, module

I have following problem: I have a .py file with some defined functions and I import a module. From this imported module I want do call a function from the parent module. How do I do this? I searched a lot but didn't found an answer. Here is some test code to show you my problem.

File 1:

```
from test2 import *

def one():
    print("one")
    pass

def two():
    print("two")
    print("now call function three from test one")

    three()


one()
two()
```

File 2: Imported as module

```
def three():
    print("three")
    print("now call function one from test 1")

    one()
```

Comment: What error do you get? It is a `NameError`?

Comment: Why can't you put `three()` in `test1.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may pass function as parameter:

Test 1:

```
from test2 import *

def one():
    print("one")
    pass

def two():
    print("two")
    print("now call function three from test one")

    three(one)  # function one()


one()
two()
```

Test 2:

```
def three(function):
    print("three")
    print("now call function one from test 1")

    function()
```

Answer (score 2):

More pythonic solution (IMHO) is this:

File `test1.py`:

```
import test2

def one():
    print("one")
    pass

def two():
    print("two")
    print("now call function three from test one")

    test2.three()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    one()
    two()
```

and `test2.py`:

```
import test1

def three():
    print("three")
    print("now call function one from test 1")

    test1.one()
```

then `python3 test1.py` produces:

```
one
two
now call function three from test one
three
now call function one from test 1
one
```

Yes, there is a circular import. Let's go step by step to see how it works:

1. `test1` is started as `__main__`, because that's the special reserved name Python uses for starting programs.
2. `test1` imports `test2` in its first line, so the parsing continues there.
3. `test2` in turn imports `test1`, that's why the first file is parsed again from the beginning, but now under its real name. The`import test2` is this time skipped, because `test2` is already a known module. At the end of the file, the `__name__` is not `__main__` and the `if` condition is false. This is important! Importing should not have any side effects.
4. control is returned to `test2`, the rest of file is parsed.
5. control is returned to `test1`, the rest of file is parsed. The condition at the bottom of the file is satisfied this time, so the execution of the main part starts with `one()`

Comment: Good point! Circular importing works only with absolute import and defer importing (import in function). It works in this particular example because of absolute import is used. Try: `from test2 import three` you will get `ImportError: cannot import name 'three'`.

Comment: @VPfB Thank you for this complete answer. Will try to implement this one.